# VB.NET WebBrowser Object Captures Remote Web Page At Low Resolution

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

**Background**
I have an ASP.NET web application with a VB.NET back end. In this application users can create payment requests which must be approved by a manager before they are sent to accounts payable for further processing. Within my request page (the page where the user enters the request information) I have a button that links to a separate .aspx page which provides a print preview of the request. When the request is approved by all of the required approvers, I have a VB.NET function that contains a `WebBrowser` object that navigates to the print preview page behind the scenes and takes a snap shot of it, then saves it as a .tiff file to an internal file share which is then picked up by a internal process and imported into another internal application called OnBase to go through processing for accounts payable.

**The Problem**
My problem is that when the my function takes the snap shot of the print preview page, the saved tiff has a lower resolution than desired. In other words, it looks kind of crappy when it is viewed through OnBase and when it is printed out.

**The Question**
How do I increase the resolution of the generated .tiff file at the time that the snapshot of the webpage is generated?

**The Code**

```
    Private Sub CaptureWebPage()
    Try
        Dim tiffFileName As String
        tiffFileName = OnBasePath & "CheckRequest_" & CurrentRequestId & ".tiff"

        Dim impersonateCode As New AliasAccount("TheUsername", "ThePassword")
        impersonateCode.BeginImpersonation()

        Dim browser As Windows.Forms.WebBrowser = New Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
        browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        browser.Navigate(OnBasePath & htmlFileName)

        While browser.ReadyState <> Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        End While

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
        browser.ClientSize = New Size(950, 768)
        Dim Height As Integer = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom
        browser.ClientSize = New Size(950, Height)
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(browser.Bounds.Width, Height)

        browser.DrawToBitmap(bmp, browser.Bounds)

        If File.Exists(tiffFileName) Then
            File.Delete(tiffFileName)
        End If

        If File.Exists(OnBasePath & htmlFileName) Then
            File.Delete(OnBasePath & htmlFileName)
        End If

        bmp.Save(tiffFileName.ToString(), ImageFormat.Tiff)
        bmp.Dispose()

        impersonateCode.EndImpersonation()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Additional Information**
I have tried to use the `.SetResolution` method of my bitmap object, but it doesn't actually change the resolution of the generated .tiff file. I have tried to Google this numerous times find a solution, but haven't found anything useful.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen "resolution" is much lower than print "resolution".  Typically desktop monitors are around 100ppi, where a normal printer on a desk might be 600dpi.

The only suggestion I have for getting a higher resolution rendering of the web page would be configure what is grabbing the screenshot to use a resolution 3x what you are using now, and then set its zoom to 300%.  Text elements and vector graphics will be rendered smoothly.  Images will still be their web resolutions, and you may even lose image quality through interpolation when sizing up.

Comment: I've considered this, but I don't know how it will scale within OnBase. Either way, I'll give it a shot and see how it turns out. Thanks again.

Comment: I've still not found a good solution for this, but I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and print the page to a virtual print driver in PDF format. I have found OnBase sometimes does strange things with image files, it doesn't like colour or grey scale TIFFs. Instead use JPEG for colour / grey scale.